# Pindo palm seedlings, can or should I move them this small if they are growing on top of each other?

Tags: palm

[image]
Last season my pindo palms had a lot of seeds germinate. The beds they are in are 6 to 7 feet in diameter. There are soo many that they are right on top of each other. Should I move them when they are this small or should i leave them be. If I should leave them, for how long? If move them, when?

Comment: Yes you can move them and you should if you want them all to survive. Eventually, the dominate plant will kill the others by starving them.